# Highcharts Datalabel formatting in spline

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need the percent sign to show in the data label of my Highcharts spline graph. so far, every iteration of format: '{point}%' breaks the whole thing, no matter where I write it. Basically, instead of the data label reading "22" it should read "22%".

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/katwood/ekko6q7b/3/).

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Enrollment By Race & Ethnicity'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Fall 2012', 'Fall 2013', 'Fall 2014', 'Fall 2015', 'Fall 2016']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Percentage'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + '%';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
    spline: {
                dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 4,
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1
            }

        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Hispanic/Latino Undergrads',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
        data: [22, 25, 28, 31, 33]
    }]
});​
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dataLabels` param in `series`.

```js
series: [{
    name: 'Hispanic/Latino Undergrads',
    marker: {
        symbol: 'square'
    },
    data: [22, 25, 28, 31, 33],
    dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.y + '%';
       }
    }
}]
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/k5rxta3j/) jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Thank you both, that was exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To format the labels for points in a series you have to either do the formatter on the `series`, or in a related `plotOptions`.

For example, using `plotOptions` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekko6q7b/4/)) ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.dataLabels.formatter)):

```
plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y + '%';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or directly on the relevant `series` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekko6q7b/5/)) ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cspline%3E.dataLabels.formatter)):

```
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return this.y + '%';
        }
    }
}]
```

See the API-links for descriptions of what values are available through `this` in the formatter.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Thank you both, that was exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated!